# How to filter a column by multiple, flexible criteria

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm writing a function to aggregate a dataframe, and it needs to be generally applicable to a wide variety of datasets. One step in this function is dplyr's `filter` function, used to select from the data only the ad campaign types relevant to the task at hand. Since I need the function to be flexible, I want ad_campaign_types as an input, but this makes filtering kind of hairy, as so:

```
aggregate_data <- function(ad_campaign_types) {
  raw_data %>%
    filter(ad_campaign_type == ad_campaign_types) -> agg_data
  agg_data
}
new_data <- aggregate_data(ad_campaign_types = c("campaign_A", "campaign_B", "campaign_C"))
```

I would think the above would work, but while it runs, oddly enough it only returns only a small fraction of what the filtered dataset should be. Is there a better way to do this?

Another tiny example of replaceable code:

```
ad_types <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d")
revenue <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(ad_types, revenue))

# Now, filtering to select only ad types "a", "b", and "d",
# which should leave us with only 7 values
new_data <- filter(data, ad_types == c("a", "b", "d"))
nrow(new_data)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For multiple criteria use `%in%` function:

```
filter(data, ad_types %in% c("a", "b", "d"))
```

you can also use "not in" criterion:

```
filter(data, !(ad_types %in% c("a", "b", "d")))
```

However notice that `%in%`'s behavior is a little bit different than `==`:

```
> c(2, NA) == 2
[1] TRUE   NA
> c(2, NA) %in% 2
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

some find one of those more intuitive than other, but you have to remember about the difference.

As for using multiple different criteria simply use chains of criteria with and/or statements:

```
filter(mtcars, cyl > 2 & wt < 2.5 & gear == 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct for filtering a dataframe. However, if you want to make a function with dplyr, you need to follow the instructions at this webpage: https://rpubs.com/hadley/dplyr-programming.

The code I would suggest.

```
library(tidyverse)
ad_types <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d")
revenue <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
df <- data_frame(ad_types = as.factor(ad_types), revenue = revenue)

aggregate_data <- function(df, ad_types, my_list) {
      ad_types = enquo(ad_types) # Make ad_types a quosure
      df %>%
          filter(UQ(ad_types) %in% my_list) # Unquosure
}

new_data <- aggregate_data(df = df, ad_types = ad_types, 
                           my_list = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

That should work!