# Why doesn't dplyr filter() work within function (i.e. using variable for column name)?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

A function for filtering, grouping and mutating data with dplyr functions. Basic pipe sequence works great outside a function, that is where I use the true column names. Put it in a function where the column name is a variable and some of the functions work but some don't most notably dplyr::filter(). For example:

```
var1 <- c('yes', NA, NA, 'yes', 'yes', NA, NA, NA, 'yes', NA, 'no', 'no', 'no', 'maybe', NA, 'maybe', 'maybe', 'maybe')

var2 <- c(1:18)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2)
```

This works fine (i.e. filters NA's):

```
df%>%filter(!is.na(var1))
```

...but this doesn't:

```
x <- "var1"

df%>%filter(!is.na(x))
```

...but this does:

```
df%>%select(x)
```

It's NA's that need to be filtered out specifically.

Tried get("x"), no good, and slicing:

```
df[!is.na(x),]
```

...no good, either.

Any ideas on how to pass a variable to filter inside (or outside) a function and why a variable is working with other dplyr functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the `sym` to convert to a symbol and then with `UQ` evaluate it

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(!is.na(UQ(sym(x))))
#     var1 var2
#1    yes    1
#2    yes    4
#3    yes    5
#4    yes    9
#5     no   11
#6     no   12
#7     no   13
#8  maybe   14
#9  maybe   16
#10 maybe   17
#11 maybe   18
```

Comment: why only with the filter function and not, for example, with select()?

Comment: @ConnerM.  `select` takes both unquoted and quoted strings i.e. `df %>% select('var1')` and `df %>% select(var1)`  This is not only with `filter`.  If you want some summarise, then you have to do the same step

Comment: Does sym belong to a specific package?

Comment: @ConnerM.  It is in `rlang`, but I think if you install `tidyverse` and load the packages, it should be loaded.  Suppose you want to summarise `df %>% summarise(count = sum(!is.na(UQ(sym(x)))))`

Comment: any idea about gather()?

Comment: @ConnerM.Suppose you want to gather based on `x`, then `gather(df, key, value, -one_of(x))`

Answer (score 4):

Since my reputation is not high enough to comment above... I would suggest taking a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45265617/6238025

> If you want to make a function with dplyr, you need to follow the instructions at this webpage: https://rpubs.com/hadley/dplyr-programming.

```
library(tidyverse)
var1 <- c('yes', NA, NA, 'yes', 
          'yes', NA, NA, NA, 'yes', NA, 'no', 
          'no', 'no', 'maybe', NA, 'maybe', 
          'maybe', 'maybe')
var2 <- c(1:18)

df <- data_frame(var1, var2)

your_function <- function(df, filter) {
      # Make filter a quosure
      filter = enquo(filter)

      df %>% 
        filter(!is.na(!!filter)) -> new_df

      return(new_df)
}
new_df <- your_function(df = df, filter = var1)
```

You could also skip the `filter = enquo(filter)` inside the function and then your call would be:

`your_function(df=df, filter=quo(var1))`

However the first way is nicer for making function calls. You won't need to remember `quo()`

That should work!

Answer (score 1):

This would also work, and it's a bit simpler - just refer to the variable containing the column name between square brackets and use (.) to refer to the input df:

```
> df %>% filter(!is.na((.)[x]))
    var1 var2
1    yes    1
2    yes    4
3    yes    5
4    yes    9
5     no   11
6     no   12
7     no   13
8  maybe   14
9  maybe   16
10 maybe   17
11 maybe   18
```

Note that this would also work within a function:

```
myfun <- function(df, var) {
  df %>%  filter(!is.na((.)[var]))
 }

 x <- "var1"
 myfun(df, x)

    var1 var2
1    yes    1
2    yes    4
3    yes    5
4    yes    9
5     no   11
6     no   12
7     no   13
8  maybe   14
9  maybe   16
10 maybe   17
11 maybe   18
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package [seplyr](https://github.com/WinVector/seplyr) that passes standard evaluation criteria to dplyr. Give it a try. You can pass normal quoted codes through it to dplyr. It makes passing parameters and writing functions in dplyr easier.

For your case:

```
install.packages("seplyr")
library(seplyr)
x<-"var1"
df%>%filter_se(paste0("!is.na(", x , ")"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `!!rlang::parse_quo()` you can filter using a character variable.

See two reproducible examples below:

```r
# Create DF
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("yes", NA, NA, "yes", "yes", NA, NA, NA, "yes", NA, "no", "no", "no", "maybe", NA, "maybe", "maybe", "maybe"),
  var2 = c(1:18)
)
```

#### Using x to define a variable

```r
x <- "var1"
FILTER <- paste0("!is.na(", x, ")")
df |> dplyr::filter(!!rlang::parse_quo(FILTER, env = parent.frame()))
#>     var1 var2
#> 1    yes    1
#> 2    yes    4
#> 3    yes    5
#> 4    yes    9
#> 5     no   11
#> 6     no   12
#> 7     no   13
#> 8  maybe   14
#> 9  maybe   16
#> 10 maybe   17
#> 11 maybe   18
```

#### Using FILTER to create a full filter statement

```r
FILTER <- "!is.na(var1)"
df |> dplyr::filter(!!rlang::parse_quo(FILTER, env = parent.frame()))
#>     var1 var2
#> 1    yes    1
#> 2    yes    4
#> 3    yes    5
#> 4    yes    9
#> 5     no   11
#> 6     no   12
#> 7     no   13
#> 8  maybe   14
#> 9  maybe   16
#> 10 maybe   17
#> 11 maybe   18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>